# Asp.Net - how to build and customize a calendar?

Tags: asp.net, templates, calendar

I was commissioned to build the following:

1. Web app to be accessed by all mobile devices - so no Flash/SilverLight/HTML5...
2. Main page will contain a calendar of current month (ability to navigate to other months is not required)
3. Each day should display one or more jobs (I am thinking 2 lines of text for each job), and each of these jobs may have a different color, depending on the time.
4. Database is SQL Server, hosted on GoDaddy, on the same hosting account as the page will live.

I am a newbie in web development and I would like to get some guidance of the best/easiest approach to implement this. Since I am a .Net Windows developer ASP.Net (or MVC) would be the preferred technology (unless you recommend a different one for this problem).
 I would really appreciate specific help on things like what control to use? Should I create a grid/table manually? How to customize each day's content, so it shows multiple jobs, each job being a couple of lines of text, but with specific color according to the job type?

(in WPF I would use templates, converters for color and everything data-bound. Do these things exist in Asp.Net?)

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those links might help you:

- Some javascript/JQuery calendar: http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/
- A databound templated calendar control for Asp.Net: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MellDataCalendar.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might look at jquery UI calendar or Telerik extension for MVC. It's not "fancy" but javascript.